# Toyota Avalon v6 3 letter 2000 model

Tags: motors

Got a nocking noice in the oil pic up in sump can .can the can I take sump off with out pulling out motor

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking but why do you think taking the oil pan off will help you in any way?  Knocking noise from low in the engine is almost always due to connecting rod "big end" bearings having failed.  The usual cause of this is lack of lubrication caused by low oil level or a problem with the oil pump.

Answer (score 0):

The oil pan is in 2 parts, upper and lower, you should be able to remove the lower with engine in the car. It is labeled No.2 Oil Pan in the image below.

I doubt the knock has anything to do with oil pump pickup.

[image]